# why program isn't running any output,?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I need the mouse go the below given axis infinitely, until i break the program.

```
import pyautogui, time

for i in range(0):
    pyautogui.moveTo(716, 234, duration = 2)
    pyautogui.moveTo(234, 600, duration = 2)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: try to give `range(n)` where `n>0` or `n=1`

Comment: Provide value for ``range()`` As you provided ``0`` it does not go inside loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop conditions are never met so your command to pyautogui are never called.
If you need an infinite loop use 'while True:'

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop

```
for i in range(0):
```

runs 0 times, the code in the for loop will therefore not execute.
If you want the for loop to run *n* times you can't change the value of 0 to *n*.

```
n = 3
for i in range(n):
    print("Hello!")
```

The above loop will output:

```
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
```

If you need the mouse go the below given axis infinitely, until you break your program, you can use a `while True` loop instead.

```
while True:
    print("hello")
```

Comment: `while` is not a function, so drop the parentheses: `while True:`